# how can i add rows one by one from one table to another in mysql

Tags: mysql

how can i add rows one by one from one table to another in mysql in stored procedure? i can do this by looping but my problem is due to some reason if mysql didn't able to insert record(eg. like data problem...) i need to run some other query in stored procedure. in this situation i need to use try catch method if any problem came i can run second query in catch block... but i didn't know how to write this logic, i tried different ways... its not working. can any one explain how to write query for this.... Thanks..

Comment: Why would you have a data problem if you are taking data from one table and putting it in another?

Comment: column length is different in both table... some times a varchar column may contain large text.... in that case... i need to copy it to other table....